# Help extruding a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I created this curve that I want to fill in but when I hit <kbd>F</kbd>, it says `Error: Cannot Make Segment`. I want to fill this in so I can then extrude it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't fill a curve with <kbd>F</kbd>, you need to make it 2D (so it needs to be flat) then choose a *Fill Mode*:

[image]

Then you can extrude under *Geometry*:

[image]